# Exchange Web Services EWS, search mails in in-place eDiscovery & hold

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to download mails that matches the in-place eDiscovery. I do a `GetDiscoverySearchConfiguration()`, then I execute `SearchMailboxes()` for each mailbox that `GetDiscoverySearchConfiguration()` returns. `SearchMailboxes()` returns `SearchPreviewItems()` where I can get the real `EmailMessage` Id but this does not have the email body, so I have to do another retrieve using `FindItems()` to get the `EmailMessage` object.

This is a very slow process, are there any other way to do this?

I would like to get all the mails that I can see in the 
[preview](http://s8.postimg.org/dbx4caqid/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `FindItems()`, use the `ExchangeService.BindToItems()` method and provide a collection of the message ids you want in batches. Restrict the property set to only the properties you need. A couple of other thoughts:
- Limit the preview response shape to just the item identifiers since you'll call `BindToItems` for the properties you need. 
- FindItems will only return the first 512 characters of the body. 
- Use paging with `SearchMailboxes()`. Optimal page size will depend on the property set. You'd have to test different page sizes to optimize.

Comment: Thanks, BindToItems was very useful. I didn't know it!